# How to reload a javascript function that creates a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In the code below, there is a click event on a table row. When you click a row it uses the id value from the first column and makes a rest call, and builds a new table with a third party function (myDataGrid) that my company uses (and I have to use it). As far as here it works good. There is no problem.

But when I click a row, it loads the second table. And When I click another row it does not reload. It only clears the table element because of this line:

```
$('#Table_1_wrapper').html("");
```

But it does not create the table again. How can I make the "myDataGrid" function load the data dynamically?

```
$scope.tableClick = function(event) {
    var tr = $('#Table_0_wrapper').find('tr');
    var id = $(event.target).parent().find("td:first").text();
    makeProxyCall("http://localhost:9090/service/getRowsWithId/"+id, function(data) {

        var dataArray = new Array([]);

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            dataArray[i] = [data[i].id, data[i].otherId,  data[i].ip, data[i].serialNumber, data[i].name, data[i].otherName];
        }   

        $('#Table_1_wrapper').html("");

        $('table[data-table-name="dt-newRows"]').myDataGrid({
            'aoColumns': [
            { 'sTitle': 'ID', 'sClass': 'essential' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Other ID', 'sClass': 'essential' },
            { 'sTitle': 'IP', 'sClass': 'essential' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Serial Number', 'sClass': 'essential' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Name', 'sClass': 'essential' },
            { 'sTitle': 'Other Name', 'sClass': 'essential' }
            ],
            'aaData': dataArray,
            'isResponsive': true
        });

    });
}
```

makeProxyCall Function:

```
window.makeProxyCall = function(url, handle) {

    return $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "/api/v2/proxy",
        dataType : "json",
        headers : {
             "Service-End-Point" : url
        },
        contentType : "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
        handle(data);
        },
        error : function(error) {
        }
    );
};
```

HTML:

```
<table ng-click="firstTableClick($event)" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered" data-table-name="dt-oldrows"></table>

<table ng-click="tableClick($event)" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered" data-table-name="dt-newrows"></table>
```

Note: When I debug while clicking different rows, makeProxyCall() always gets the true values.

Comment: Can you add your HTML. Also who is calling $scope.tableClick

Comment: @Sandeeproop added HTML

Answer (score 1):

Most jquery table plugins have a built in reload method. Because most of these grids do not only use the html markup on the page they also use some variables and values to store the current state of the table.

If the "myDataGrid" grid doesn't have such a reload method, look for a dedicated destroy method. This will usually unload all held resources of the grid.

Without knowing the plugin I can't give you further advice.

Comment: There is a reloadAjax() function. I will try to use it, thanks.